# How can I solve this in Excel? I need to nest various functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to solve column D (count). Please see image, it's an example and I have manually calculated D to clarify my problem. For each repeated transaction that a user has, excel should add plus 1, but should not add count from other users.

[image: example]

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$8,A2,C$2:C$8,C2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(A2&"|"&C2=$A$2:$A$8&"|"&$C$2:$C$8))
```

---

Formula needs to fill down!

---

Or, Using <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, N(A2:A8&"|"&C2:C8=TOROW(A2:A8&"|"&C2:C8)),
     MMULT(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α),,,0)))
```

---

Or, bit shorter, though the transaction references will be different, but still as an option.

```
=LET(
     α, N(A2:A8&"|"&C2:C8=TOROW(A2:A8&"|"&C2:C8)),
     MMULT(α,TOCOL(RIGHT(C2:C8)/1)^0))
```

---

Or, simple with <kbd>COUNTIFS()</kbd> as mentioned by @VBasic2008 Sir.

[image]

---

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,A2,$C$2:$C$8,C2)
```

---